# Reassign variable value in C#

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

Is it safe, or at least a "good practice", in C# to do things like this:

```
string cnt;

....
cnt = cnt.Trim();
```

(In C, for instance, sometimes, you have to be careful with that kind of assignment.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's safe and it's often a good idea with strings since they are immutable (the original object is unchanged, `Trim()` returns a reference to a new object).